# how to measure the width of a tkinter canvas text

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was wondering how to measure the width of a text in tkinter canvas. I have a text displayed somewhere:

```
myCanvas.create_text(400,410, text="This is my text", tags="my_tag")
```

and at some point there is a shape (polygon line) that may overlap when the text gets longer (text will be changed with `.itemconfigure()`). In this case I wanted to break the text in lines, which works well with the `width` option.

To figure out if objects overlap there are a couple of possible methods: `find_overlapping()` or `find_enclosed()`, however, they do require 4 coordinates and `myCanvas.coords("my_tag")` only returns 2 coordinates. How could I figure out the other `x2`, `y2`?

An alternative was to use `find_closest()`, however, there are a bunch of shapes closer than the overlapping one, so that is not accurate.

Another alternative was that I could figure out the intersecting coordinate and then just take the distance to the x coordinate of the text and double that as a width (since text gets drawn from the center), for example:

intersection point at `(350,405)` => `width = 2 * (400-350)`

However, since the shape is a line (part of a polygon) that goes diagonal, I'm not sure how get the intersection point other than having a loop that creates a line that slowly increases till it overlaps with an object, for example:

```
text_center = (400,410)
start_x = text_center[0]
start_y = text_center[1]
extender = 1
while(myCanvas.find_overlapping(start_x, start_y, start_x+entender, start_y == ())
     myCanvas.delete("mytestline")
     extender += 1
     myCanvas.create_line(start_x, start_y, start_x+extender, start_y, tags="mytestline")
overlapping_point = (start_x+extender, start_y)
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bbox` method will return the bounding box of any item or group of items on the canvas. The bounding box is the smallest rectangle that contains the elements, give or take a pixel or two. The returned value is a tuple of the two coordinates.

The following example creates a text item, gets and displays the bounding box, and also uses the coordinates to draw a rectangle around the text so you can visually see that the numbers are correct.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
myCanvas = tk.Canvas(root)
myCanvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

item_id = myCanvas.create_text(100,50, text="This is my text", tags="my_tag")
bbox = myCanvas.bbox(item_id)
myCanvas.create_rectangle(bbox, outline="red")
myCanvas.create_text(100, 70, text=f"bbox: {bbox}")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]